# Checking for something in every line of a text file using python (Beginner)

Tags: python, file

I've been assigned to make a basic login function using various logins already stored in a text file, the problem I'm having is it checks the first line of the file.

```py
def login_system():
    global logged_in
    username = input("Please Enter Your Username:   ")
    password = input("Please Enter Your Password:   ")
    f = open("staff.txt", "r")
    for line in f:
        if line == username+":"+password:
            print ("You Are Logged In")
            logged_in += 1
            clear()
            return True
        else:
            print ("Your username and password combination is incorrect, please see the administrator")
            logged_in += 0
            return False
```

and this is the contents of my "staff.txt" file.

> username:password
>
> username2:password2
>
> example:example

Forgot to mention that when it outputs the string it outputs it * how many lines are in my text file, I will fix that later.

Comment: Note how you `return False` if the first line is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This only checks the first line of the file because the function returns true if the usename and password are correct or else it returns false. Once the function returns True or False the function is going back to where you called it.
this should fix it:

```
def login_system():
    lines = 0
    global logged_in
    username = input("Please Enter Your Username:   ")
    password = input("Please Enter Your Password:   ")
    f = open("staff.txt", "r")
    for line in f:
        if line == username + ":" + password:
            print ("You Are Logged In")
            logged_in += 1
            clear()
        else:
            print ("Your username and password combination is incorrect, please see the administrator")
        lines += 1

    return lines == logged_in
```

Comment: This will return true if all of the usernames and passwords were correct else it will
return false.